# SQL getting first distinct value from table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to check if this SQL is correct.

`"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Entry Date] FROM [" + group + "]) WHERE [Entry Date]>#" + initDate + "# ORDER BY [Entry Date]"`

**Thank you in advance**

**Solved :** I found that the sql works perfectly. It's just I made a small mistake in my program. Now solved.

Comment: What problem you are facing with this query ?

Comment: I'm creating a c# program. My program gets stuck in the middle. I want to see if the problem is here or somewhere else.

Comment: run the query separately to check if you are getting results, and use debugger to trace the issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
select min([Entry Date])
from [group]
where [Entry Date] > #" + initDate
```

or this:

```
select top 1 *
from [group]
where [Entry Date] > #" + initDate
order by [Entry Date]
```

Comment: I want to select distinct row.

Comment: @Harshan01 . . . That should be the second query.

Comment: Because there are duplicate values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT B.* FROM (
SELECT [EntryDate] FROM Group

EXCEPT

SELECT [EntryDate] FROM (

SELECT [EntryDate]
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EntryDate]) AS Rown 
from Group 
                        )A WHERE Rown > 1 )B JOIN Group C ON a.[EntryDate] = B.[EntryDate]

WHERE [Entry Date] > #" + initDate
ORDER BY [Entry Date]
```

Comment: MS Access doesn't have row_number

Comment: Duly noted. Actually I didn't notice the 'MS Access' tag earlier.